# how to Order a DataTable By more than one condition using AsEnumerable().OrderBy?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, datatable

Just like in TSQL:

```
select * from aTable where (aCondition) order by AnIntegerField desc, ADateField
```

how to sort a DataTable using:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(--two conditions --)
```

Comment: You do realize that `AsEnumerable()` means that all sorting will be done in-memory, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use OrderBy first, then [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby) (for ascending) or [ThenByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending) (for descending).

From the Microsoft documentation:

```
    string[] fruits = { "grape", "passionfruit", "banana", "mango", 
                          "orange", "raspberry", "apple", "blueberry" };

    // Sort the strings first by their length and then 
    //alphabetically by passing the identity selector function.
    IEnumerable<string> query =
        fruits.OrderBy(fruit => fruit.Length).ThenBy(fruit => fruit);
```

or for VB (since question is tagged with both):

```vb
    ' Create an array of strings.
    Dim fruits() As String = _
        {"grape", "passionfruit", "banana", "mango", _
         "orange", "raspberry", "apple", "blueberry"}

    ' Sort the strings first by their length and then 
    ' alphabetically by passing the identity function.
    Dim query As IEnumerable(Of String) = _
        fruits _
        .OrderBy(Function(fruit) fruit.Length) _
        .ThenBy(Function(fruit) fruit)
```

Comment: the data table is huge and the best performance is required, do you think it'll be better than using .Select()

Comment: @Ala You can't use `Select()` for sorting.

Comment: @svick according to my research, i've found that using     `AsEnumerable().OrderBy()` is much better than     `Select()` if we take the performance into consideration and for one condition, that's why i didn't mention the     `Select()` in this question, 
I believe that the answer here is correct, but it's actually implementing two sorts, do you think it's still faster than           `Select()`, please tell me if i have to ask a different question for this issue.

Comment: @svick i can [use `Select()` for sorting and for many conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx)

Comment: OK, this answer has fulfilled my question, i'll ask another question for the performance issue,